# Angular2 bind ngModel from ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm rendering my `textarea` dynamically using `ngFor` however I'm not sure how I can pass the `ngModel` to bind it in my function.

```
<div *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-sm-3': swaggerParamLength=='3', 'col-sm-9': swaggerParamLength=='1'}">
   <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" id="{{inputSearch.name}}" rows="3" class="search-area-txt" attr.placeholder="Search Product {{inputSearch.name}}"
     [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.name"></textarea>
  </div>
```

textarea example:
[image]

textarea is render based on the length of the response I get from api call in my case `searchBoxCount` is basically `searchBoxCount.length`, so if it `length` is = 1 then it will only render 1 `textarea` if its 3 then it will show 3 `textareas`. The objs have different names (example: id/email/whatever), so ngModel is based on the obj name from the json object.

How do I bind `inputSearch.name` to my function `getQueryString()`

```
 getQueryString() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    let idInputValue = inputSearch.name; //bind it here

    return "?id=" + idInputValue
        .split("\n") // Search values are separated by newline and put it in array collection.
        .filter(function(str) {
            return str !== ""
        })
        .join("&id=");
}
```

Search func where getQueryString() is called

```
searchProduct() {
    let queryString1 = this.getQueryString();
    this._searchService.getProduct(queryString1)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

I know how to do it if the `ngModel` is not coming from the `ngFor`, is there another way to get the value from the `textarea` without `ngModel`? maybe that's the only way or if I can still use `ngModel`.

Comment: Why don't you directly access the searchBoxCount array and use it's element in getQueryString? I think searchBoxCount is an array right?

Comment: @KaranDesai it is an array[] yes, can you show an example?

Comment: I am a bit confused, can you provide more details?  When does getQueryString() get called?  What do you want to get in that function, the value from each of the textareas or from a specific one?

Comment: @StevenLuke getQueryString() is being called when a click event happens in my case `<button (click)="searchProduct()">`, I've added the search function where getQueryString is being called.

Comment: Since `ngModel` is dynamic coming from an api response.

Comment: There are presumably multiple values inside searchBoxCount, which is why you need the ngFor to get each of the inputSearch objects.  Do you need the .name value from every inputSearch instance (each of the objects in the searchBoxCount) or from a specific inputSearch object?

Comment: searchBoxCount is just the array objs I get back from api response. So if the response only have 1 obj it will only render 1 input field, each input is different. For example 1 input can search `id=33`, or `email=x@x.com` or can be both `id and email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary of current state**

First, let me summarize where your data is.  You have a list of one or more objects named `searchBoxCount`.  Each of the elements in the list is an object which has a name property, so you could, for example, call `let name = this.searchBoxCount[0].name;` to get the name of the first object in the list.

In the HTML template you use ngFor to loop through all of the objects in the `searchBoxCount` list, and in each iteration you assign the object to a local (to the ngFor) variable named `inputSearch`.  You then bind the input from the textarea created in each loop iteration to the `name` property for that iteration's `inputSearch` object.

**How to get your data**

The key here is that the `inputSearch` is the same Object as is stored in `searchBoxCount` at some particular index (index 0 for the first object, etc...).  So when the ngModel is tied to `inputSearch.name` it is also bout to `searchBoxCount[n].name`.  External to the ngFor, you would loop through the `searchBoxCount` list to get each name you need.

**As a consequence**

Based on the comments on the original post, it sounds like you can have one or 
more names that you need to include in the query string output.  That means for your `getQueryString()` to work, you have to loop through the list (or as in this case, let the list loop for us):

```
getQueryString() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    let result : string = "?id=";
    this.searchBoxCount.forEach(
        (inputSearch:any) => {  //Not the same variable, but same objects as in the ngFor
            result = result + inputSearch.name + "&id=";
    });
    result = result.slice(0, result.length - 4);  //trim off the last &id=
    return result;
}
```

**Edit: Multiple different fields with different names**

From the comments on this post, it now is clear each inputSearch has its own key to be used in the query string, that is stored in the name property.  You need to preserve that name, which means you **can't** bind the ngModel to it.  Otherwise the user will destroy the name by typing in their own text and there will be no way to get the correct key back.  To that end, you need to store bind the ngModel to some other property of the inputSearch object.  I am going to assume the object has a value property, so it looks like this:

```
{
    name: "id",
    value: "33\n44"
}
```

That is, each inputSearch has a name, and the value will have one or more values, separated by new line.  You would then have to change the HTML template to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount; let i = index" 
     [ngClass]="{'col-sm-3': swaggerParamLength=='3', 'col-sm-9': 
     swaggerParamLength=='1'}">
   <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" 
             id="{{inputSearch.name}}" rows="3" class="search-area-txt" 
             attr.placeholder="Search Product {{inputSearch.name}}"
             [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.value"></textarea>
</div>
```

Notice that I changed the ngModel from `inputSearch.name` to <strike>`inputSearch?.value` (the ? allows for null if there is no value to begin with)</strike> `inputSearch.value`.  The getQueryString() method then looks something like this:

```
getQueryString() {
    let result:string = "?";

    //for each of the input search terms...
    this.searchBoxCount.forEach( (inputSearch:any) => {
        // first reparse the input values to individual key value pairs
        let inputValues:string = inputSearch.value.split("\n")
             .filter(function(str) { return str !== "" })
             .join("&" + inputSearch.name + "=");
        // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
        result = result + 
             inputSearch.name + 
             "=" + 
             inputValues +
             "&"
    });
    // remove trailing '&'
    result = result.slice(0, result.length - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Note, using RxJs this is probably easier but I am testing vanilla javascript.

Using this, if the user entered two IDs (33 and 44), a single sku, and two emails, the result would be `?id=33&id=24&sku=abc123&email=name@compa.ny&email=an.other@compa.ny`

Comment: what's the splice for? the search should look like `searchAPI?id=` if user used id field or if its sku `searchAPI?sku=`.

Comment: The string created in the forEach() ends with an extra `&id=` so the splice cuts that out.

Comment: except that it will not always be an `&id`, it can be `sku` or `code` see the image I uploaded in my original post. The idea is to search multiple ids, skus, codes when user press enter so it would put the value in a new line.

Comment: "if user used id field or if its sku searchAPI?sku="  Ooooh.  How do you know if the user used the id field of if they used the sku field?  You can't go by the `name` field since that gets trashed by the user input...  It seems to me like you may need to redesign a bit.  Perhaps, instead of binding ngModel to `inputSearch.name` (which lets the user destroy the name) you should bind it to some other property in `inputSearch`, perhaps `inputSearch.value` if it exists.

Comment: Can you show an example of that? but Yeah it should let the user enter multiple values when they press enter that's why there's a `.split('\n')` in the getQueryString() function and that's why I used `textarea`.

Comment: Updated the response with changes to allow multiple different search terms and multiple values for each.

Comment: Will check but inputValueString cannot find, unless that's from your testing which is now not being found.

Comment: Sorry, it was.  In the post it is replaced with inputValues.

Comment: can you explain about more about `?.value`? because that's giving me an error `operator cannot be used in the assignment`

Comment: Typically, the ?. operator allows the use of null (for example to show a value which may not exist until some time after the component was created).  But it looks like the ngModel does not allow it - maybe because it is two-way binding not just one-way.  Take the ? out in this case.

Comment: I see, is there a possible way to do the search term say search for `id` or `sku` or `code` as they will return the same object if they all match in the db anyway. Because at the moment it requires all the fields to be filled otherwise I get an error of `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`